# fill the second combo box based on the first combo box

Tags: vba, excel

I have 2 comboboxes in an excel userform and i need the first combobox to affect what is listed in the second. The table which i am getting the data from on a sheet in excel looks like image attached:

[image].

The data goes on with business names and individuals. What I would like `combobox2` to do is when say DT limited is selected in `combobox1` then `combobox2` will only show john and steve for selection.

Can anyone help, I am new to this?

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
With ComboBox1 'Your first combobox
.Clear


.AddItem "Users" 
.AddItem "Salary"   ' Add main combobox Category

End With
End Sub



Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()

Dim index As Integer
 index = ComboBox1.ListIndex

 ComboBox2.Clear ' clear your dependent combobox

Select Case index
     Case Is = 0   ' Add Subcategory Display items
         With ComboBox2
         .AddItem "John"
         .AddItem "Angie"
         .AddItem "Sam"
     End With
 Case Is = 1
     With ComboBox2
         .AddItem "20000"
         .AddItem "45000"
         .AddItem "80000"
     End With

End Select

End Sub
```

Comment: the only issue with what you have provided above is that the list is continuously added to with new businesses and individual linked to that business. i need the comboboxes to be able to automatically pick this up, the number of entries is not fixed

Comment: @benjaminsolanke Just add a `ComboBox2.Clear` line. Please be nice with the people that are trying to help you for free.

Comment: @AK47 You should not provide code if the one who ask don't show any effort to develop his own code.

Answer (score 0):

This code will resolve your proplem.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Dim RowMax As Integer
Dim wsh As Worksheet
Dim countExit As Integer
Dim CellCombo1 As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer

Set wsh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
RowMax = wsh.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
'find last row of sheet in column A

ComboBox1.Clear
'clear all value of comboBox1

With ComboBox1

    For i = 2 To RowMax
    'Run each row of column A

    countExit = 0
    CellCombo1 = wsh.Cells(i, "A").Value

            For j = i To 2 Step -1
            'just show value not duplicate

            If CellCombo1 = wsh.Cells(j, "A").Value Then
            countExit = countExit + 1
            End If
            Next j
        If countExit = 0 Then

        ElseIf countExit > 1 Then
            Else
            .AddItem CellCombo1
            End If
    Next i

End With

End Sub
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
Dim RowMax As Integer
Dim wsh As Worksheet
Dim countExit As Integer
Dim CellCombo2 As String
Dim i As Integer

Set wsh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
RowMax = wsh.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
'find last row of sheet in column A

ComboBox2.Clear
'clear all value of comboBox2

With ComboBox2
    For i = 2 To RowMax
        If wsh.Cells(i, "A").Value = ComboBox1.Text Then
        'Just show value of mapping with column A
        .AddItem wsh.Cells(i, "B").Value
        Else
        End If
    Next i
End With
End Sub
```